# OnClick event to Hide and Toggle Page Section

Tags: javascript, html, css, function

I created two(2) sections.I want to hide a section by default, with a button under it that says “Show More”.

Something like this--- (https://www.livermoretreeremoval.com/tree-service-ulmar) under the "**Ulmar Tree Services Top Sights**" section.

If the button is clicked, the hidden Section should appear, and the button Text should change to “Show Less”.

If the Button is clicked again, the visible Section should become hidden again, and the Button Text should say “Show More”.

So when hidden, the button says “Show More”, and when visible the button says “Show Less”.

## Here’s my JavaScript below:

`

```
function toggleBlock() {
// get the block
    var myBlock = document.getElementById(‘service-area-two’);

// get the current value of the block’s display property
    var displaySetting = myBlock.style.display;

// also get the block button, so we can change what it says
    var blockButton = document.getElementById(‘Show More’);

// now toggle the block and the button text, depending on current state
    if (displaySetting == ‘block’) {
// block is visible. hide it
    myBlock.style.display = ‘none’;
// change button text
    blockButton.innerHTML = ‘Show Less’;
}
else {
// block is hidden. show it
myBlock.style.display = ‘block’;
// change button text
blockButton.innerHTML = ‘Show More’;
}
}
```

`

The Section ID: **service-area-two**
The Button Name is: **ToggleButton**

I know I’m doing a lot of things wrong.

How can I get this button to work?

Comment: I understand what you want, but what are the issue you are facing? Does your console logs some errors?

Comment: Post the code as run-snippet. @Gamicord

Comment: @gamicord are you looking like  this https://media.geeksforgeeks.org/wp-content/uploads/20201031002151/ex1.gif

Comment: Is that correct? 
var blockButton = document.getElementById(‘Show More’);

Answer (score 0):

So as for the button, the show more and show less is not working is what I understood. I think the mistake here is `innerHTML`. `innerHTML` means the actual HTML inside the block like for example:

`button.innerHTML = '<img src="---'">'`

Finally, change `innerHTML` to `innerText`.

Answer (score 0):

Use the hidden attribute.
So:

```
<div hidden id="service-area-two">
    // content
</div>
<button id="Show More" onclick="toggleBlock()">Show more</button>
```

And the JavaScript logic like this:

```
function toggleBlock() {
    var myBlock = document.getElementById("service-area-two");

    var blockButton = document.getElementById("Show More");

    if (myBlock.hidden) {
        blockButton.innerHTML = "Show Less";
        myBlock.hidden = false;
    } else {
        blockButton.innerHTML = "Show More";
        myBlock.hidden = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: I am so grateful. Now, I will simply like to wrap this JavaScript inside an HTML onclick button. Something like this--<button onclick="myFunction()">Click me</button>

How should I write the HTML to the wrap this your JavaScript Code in the button?

Regards

Comment: -- I have applied the Code and somehow it's not working. 

Here's the page I want to implement the Code: https://treeremoval.ga/tree-service-ulmar/#ShowMore

Any further help, advice or assistance you can render me?

Thanks

Comment: I have applied the Code and Oh my goodness, it worked like a charm. Thanks so much. The issue is now Resolved

Comment: @Gamicord glad it helped. Can you mark my answer as correct so stackoverflow nows the question is answered.